# Select rows from a DataFrame based on last characters of values in a column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to select rows from columns with last word as 'oo' in Column A how can I do this.

I went through the link :- [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

What I tried :-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo baroo foos bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
print(df)
#      A      B  C   D
# 0  foo    one  0   0
# 1  bar    one  1   2
# 2  foo    two  2   4
# 3  bar  three  3   6
# 4  foo    two  4   8
# 5  baroo    two  5  10
# 6  foos    one  6  12
# 7  foo  three  7  14

print(df.loc[df['A'] == 'foo'])
```

This is giving me dataframe with entries

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
2  foo    two  2   4
4  foo    two  4   8
7  foo  three  7  14
```

What should I try to get 5th row along with the other rows which I got?
Expected Output :-

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
2  foo    two  2   4
4  foo    two  4   8
5  baroo    two  5  10
7  foo  three  7  14
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
df[df.A.str.endswith('oo')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean operator

```
print(df.loc[( df.A == 'foo')|(df.A =='baroo') , :])
```